# Get single records when duplicate records exist in 2 table

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables. `TableA` is the sales and `TableB` is the leads table. I'm trying to see if the people in the leads `TableB` made a purchase and their name appears 
on the sales `TableA`. If they do I only want the name of people who appears 
on both tables.

TableA (Sales)

```
 customer   school            email     address    state    phone   Sales
 john doe   hight middle    111@hu.z   111 updown   wi     2222222  $500 
 john doe   hight middle    111@hu.z   111 updown   wi     2222222  $100 
 zow hi     hight middle    222@hop.c  111 updown   wi     2222222  $200 
 calispo    dwight elem     s@dw.co.za 34 jimm elis CA     35450456 $1,000 
 Jordan     clift high       jp@hy.zut  1 unversity GA     11111111 $100
```

TableB (Leads)

```
 customer       school           email       address    state
 john doe      hight middle    111@hu.z    111 updown     wi
 Kawi          hight middle     k@nop.c     111 updown    wi
 calispo       dwight elem    s@dw.co.za   34 jimm elis   CA
```

What I want to see:

```
 customer   school           email       address    state
 john doe   hight middle    111@hu.z   111 updown   wi     2222222   $500
 alispo     dwight elem     s@dw.co.za 34 jimm elis CA     35450456 $1,000
```

I try this query but it is returning duplicate of the info that I want

```
 SELECT a.email as [sales_school]
  ,b.email[leadds_insti]
  ,a.*
  ,b.*
  FROM [dbo].[Sales] a 
  right JOIN leads b ON a.email= b.email
```

Comment: Why do you want john doe with $500, not $100 (or sum $600) - is there any requirement which record to select?

Comment: And general comment: don't use aliases a, b, c... for your tables, use something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find highest sale for each email and then join it with leads:

```
WITH maxsales AS
(SELECT 
sales.*,
ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY sales.email ORDER BY Sales.Sales DESC) AS rn
FROM [dbo].[Sales]
) 
SELECT maxsales.email as [sales_school]
  ,leads.email[leadds_insti]
  ,maxsales .*
  ,leads.*
FROM maxsales 
INNER JOIN leads ON leads.email= maxsales.email
WHERE maxsales.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the name of leads in the Sales table then this should do

```
SELECT TableB.*
FROM TableB
WHERE TableB.email IN
(SELECT email from TableA)
```